# Using ko array filter to display range of dates

Tags: knockout.js

I am new to learning knockout js and I was trying to use array filter to get range of date from 2 inputs, basically a start date and a end date. This start date and end date comes from input fields. I get a array containing a lot of dates.

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input  type="text" class="form-control"  data-provide="datepicker" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" name="birthday"  data-bind="value : startDate"/>  
        </div>    
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control"  data-provide="datepicker" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" name="birthday"  data-bind="value : endDate" />  
        </div>    
     </div>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: alldata">
  <tr>
     <td class="text-center"><span data-bind="text: $data.INSERT_DT"></span></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

So I am trying to use `ko.utils.arrayFilter`but I am not really sure how it works. But what I want to achieve is get all the dates from the array falling in the middle`self.startdate()` and `self.endDate` Here is my script.

```
//This basically means showing all dates in observable
        self.startDate = ko.observable('2000-12-01');
        self.endDate = ko.observable('9999-12-01');

        self.NewdateFilter = ko.observable();

        self.filterDate = ko.computed(function(data){
           var value1 = self.startDate();
           var value2 = self.endDate();
           return ko.utils.arrayFilter( function(){
               //not really sure how to use this.
           });
        });

        self.alldata = ko.observableArray();

        self.viewAllInvoice = function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: BASEURL + 'index.php/main/getDates/' ,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            })
            .done(function(invoices) {
            self.alldata.removeAll();
            $.each(invoices, function (index, invoice) {

                    self.alldata.push(invoice);
                });
        })
            .fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
                alert(status);
            })
            .always(function(data){                 
            });
        };
    self.viewAllInvoice();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ko.utils.arrayFilter` works like any array filter function.

It takes an array as first argument and a function (called "predicate") as the second argument.

The predicate function is then called for each array element and is supposed to return `true` or `false`, depending on  whether you want that particular element in the result or not.

```
ko.utils.arrayFilter([1,2,3,4,5], function isEven(item) {
    return item % 2 === 0;
});  // -> [2,4]
```

So, in your context:

```
self.alldata = ko.observableArray();
self.startDate = ko.observable('2000-12-01');
self.endDate = ko.observable('9999-12-01');

self.filterDate = ko.computed(function(data) {
    var value1 = self.startDate();
    var value2 = self.endDate();
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.alldata(), function (item) {
        return value1 < item.date && item.date < value2;
    });
});
```

---

Side note: Your `viewAllInvoice()` function can be simplified quite a bit.

```
self.viewAllInvoice = function() {
    $.get(BASEURL + 'index.php/main/getDates/')
    .done(self.alldata)
    .fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
        alert(status);
    })
};
self.viewAllInvoice();
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for the explanation I appreciate it ! Now I know what it does, but where do I call the self.filterDate?

Comment: You don't call it at all. It's a computed observable. You use it in your viewmodel like you would use any other observable, that's the whole point. ;)

Comment: Sorry I might sound dumb but I wrote everything , but now when I change the dates on the html page, table still stays the same, what am I doing wrong? and console does not have any error.

Comment: Only if you bound the table like this: `foreach: alldata`. You want to bind it like this `foreach: filterDate`. (Also, I'm pretty sure you want to call that `filteredData`. A computed is not an action, it's the *result* of an action.)

Comment: Yea I did that, and I tried to write console.log(data); after filterDate but it says everything is undefined on my console hence I am not getting any results

Comment: Okay fixed it, Thanks for the explanation appreciate it, you made it really easy for me :)

Comment: You're welcome. What was the reason for the `undefined`?

Comment: I forgot to change item.date too item.INSERT_DT